# I'm able to select files from the dropdown but how can i take those selected files to the controller.js when a button is clicked

Tags: html, angularjs

The HTML file that am using is below:

```
<label for="lfiles">LFILES</label> <select class="chosen-select"
data-placeholder="Select Files" chosen multiple
ng-model="upgradepatch.lFiles" options="bscPatchFiles"
ng-options="list for list in bscPatchFiles"></select>

<input type="button" value="Upload" ng-click="ButtonClick()" />
<span ng-bind="Message"></span>
```

The controller.js file is below:

```
$scope.loadSWFiles = function(){
$http.get('showDirectories.do?id='+$scope.bscId).success(function(data) {
$scope.bscPatchFiles=data;
}); 
}
$scope.ButtonClick = function () { 
$scope.Message = "Patch Upload."
        console.log('ButtonClick');
       }
```

Comment: it will be available in the $scope.upgradepatch.lFiles inside controller

Comment: In what way i should change the code to get the details.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example in which you can select multiple options from dropdown by pressing the shift command and the option you want to select simultaneously.

```js
var app = angular.module('role', []);

app.controller('fooController', function($scope){
    $scope.roles = [{id:1, name:"Administrator"}, {id:2, name: "Student"}];
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.roles = [ {id:1, name:"Administrator"} ];
    $scope.ButtonClick = function() {
      console.log($scope.user.roles);
    };
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.5" data-semver="1.3.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="role" data-ng-controller="fooController">
  <select multiple class="form-control" 
    data-ng-model="user.roles" 
    data-ng-options="role.name for role in roles track by role.id" 
    required=""></select>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" ng-click="ButtonClick()" />
</body>

</html>
```

This is how we select multiples from dropdown (Press shift button to select multiple) with and without ng-options and bind it with controller.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('staticSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     multipleSelect: []
    };

    $scope.ButtonClick = function() {
      alert($scope.data.multipleSelect);
    };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - multiSelect</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="staticSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="multipleSelect"> Multiple select: </label><br>
    <select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="data.multipleSelect" multiple>
      <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
    </select><br>
    <tt>multipleSelect = {{data.multipleSelect}}</tt><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Upload" ng-click="ButtonClick()" />
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```